# PHP-EWS fails on more than one attachment

Tags: php, exchangewebservices, php-ews

I use [James Armes's PHP-EWS library](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews).

The following code works fine with single attachments, but fails with multiply files.

```
<?php
$msgRequest->MessageDisposition = 'SaveOnly';

$msgResponse = $ews->CreateItem($msgRequest);
$msgResponseItems = $msgResponse->ResponseMessages->CreateItemResponseMessage->Items;

// Create attachment(s)
$attachments = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($message_details['attachment'] as $attachment) {
    $attachments[$i] = new EWSType_FileAttachmentType();
    $attachments[$i]->Content = file_get_contents($attachment['path'] . '/' . $attachment['file']);
    $attachments[$i]->Name = $attachment['file'];
    $i++;
}
//
// Attach files to message
$attRequest = new EWSType_CreateAttachmentType();
$attRequest->ParentItemId = $msgResponseItems->Message->ItemId;
$attRequest->Attachments = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfAttachmentsType();
$attRequest->Attachments->FileAttachment = $attachments;

$attResponse = $ews->CreateAttachment($attRequest);
$attResponseId = $attResponse->ResponseMessages->CreateAttachmentResponseMessage->Attachments->FileAttachment->AttachmentId;

// Save message id from create attachment response
$msgItemId = new EWSType_ItemIdType();
$msgItemId->ChangeKey = $attResponseId->RootItemChangeKey;
$msgItemId->Id = $attResponseId->RootItemId;

// Send and save message
$msgSendRequest = new EWSType_SendItemType();
$msgSendRequest->ItemIds = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseItemIdsType();
$msgSendRequest->ItemIds->ItemId = $msgItemId;
$msgSendRequest->SaveItemToFolder = true;
$msgSendResponse = $ews->SendItem($msgSendRequest);
$response = $msgSendResponse->ResponseMessages->SendItemResponseMessage;
?>
```

$ews->SendItem() returns this error:

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:ErrorSchemaValidation] The request
>   failed schema validation: The required attribute 'Id' is missing.

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer here:

https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/issues/132

Basically Exchange does not use an array if there is only one attachment, so an additional check is required to determine where to get the ID from.

```
if(!is_array($attResponse->ResponseMessages->CreateAttachmentResponseMessage))
    $attResponseId = $attResponse->ResponseMessages->CreateAttachmentResponseMessage->Attachments->FileAttachment->AttachmentId;
else {
    $attResponseId = $attResponse->ResponseMessages->CreateAttachmentResponseMessage[0]->Attachments->FileAttachment->AttachmentId;
}
```

Exchange uses the same structure with recipients. I find this inconsistent, however I am sure there is a reason behind it.

I hope someone will benefit from raising this.